# How to Increase partition size of ubuntu on external harddisk

Tags: partitioning

i just installed ubuntu 14 on my 1.0TB external hd. I only use 700GB for the installation and 20GB for swap. I thought the remaining 280GB will be available for me to store files from windows anytime i wish to do so. But when I logged into windows, it does not see the partition at all. I need the 280GB space back.
So i need help on how to make my ubuntu to completely use up the 1.0TB or help on how to make windows see the 280GB space.
Thank you.

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu and show us a screenshot of the program GParted (making sure you select your external hard disk from the drop down menu on the top right), or give us the output of `sudo parted /dev/sdb print free`, assuming that your external hard disk is `sdb`. This will shed some light on what's happening with the 280GB space.

Comment: I already solved the problem. I boot into the new ubuntu on the external harddrive, then connect to the internet, browse the software centre for gparted, downloaded it, lunch it click on the unallocated partition, make it ntfs, gave it a label, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: After review, I found a mistake. You'll need to boot a
>   liveCD/USB in order to re-size a system partition, and [the Ubuntu
>   14.04.1 LiveCD/USB image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) comes with GParted.

Click on the partition you wish to expand, then click the orange arrow to expand it. If another partition exists, you may need to delete it.
[image]

To reformat a partition for windows, right click the partition, then choose "Format", and use the NTFS file system.

Comment: Won't work - you can't run gparted and modify the running system's partition.

Comment: Then he can use a LiveCD.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  But I thought perhaps you might want to edit your answer so it would not incorrectly instruct the user to install gparted rather than use a LiveCD/USB.

Comment: I already solved the problem. I boot into the new ubuntu on the external harddrive, then connect to the internet, browse the software centre for gparted, downloaded it, lunch it click on the unallocated partition, make it ntfs, gave it a label, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't modify a mounted partition, and can't unmount the partition for the running system, the easiest way would be to boot from the Ubuntu install disk into a live system.  From there, you can run `gparted`, choose the disk that contains Ubuntu, and resize that partition.

Just drag the end of the partition toward the beginning (from right to left), leaving space at the end.

Then, you can create a new partition in the unused space, either with gparted (change type to NTFS or FAT32), or you should be able to use Windows, if you want.

Comment: I already solved the problem. I boot into the new ubuntu on the external harddrive, then connect to the internet, browse the software centre for gparted, downloaded it, lunch it click on the unallocated partition, make it ntfs, gave it a label, and that's it.