# I deleted all of my partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, gparted

A few months ago, I had Windows 8 as the only operative system on my computer and I wanted to install Ubuntu, having both operative systems on my pc (dual boot). However, after supposedly installing Ubuntu, I wanted both Ubuntu and Windows 8 to appear on the screen when booting (so I could choose which one I wanted to work with), and that's when the problem appeared. In the terminal, I followed a tutorial that could make the dual boot work (I don't remember what I wrote) and, all of a sudden, all of my partitions were gone. I initiated the computer again and it would go straight to the BIOS. Then, after several tries, I somehow installed Ubuntu and have been working on it since. However, I know that all of my partitions are messed up and now that I need both Windows and Ubuntu on my pc, I really need to figure this out. I really appreciate any help that you can give.

Here's a print screen of gparted 
[image]
which shows all of the partitions on the computer.

Comment: From the picture it appears that Windows has been deleted.  You would need to re-install Windows following the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be found [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519849/how-to-increase-partition-size-of-ubuntu-on-external-harddisk/519852?noredirect=1#comment706471_519852).

> You'll need to boot a liveCD/USB in order to re-size a system
>   partition, and [the Ubuntu
>   14.04.1 LiveCD/USB image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519849/how-to-increase-partition-size-of-ubuntu-on-external-harddisk/519852?noredirect=1#comment706471_519852) comes with GParted.
>
> Click on the partition you wish to expand, then click the orange arrow
>   to expand it. If another partition exists, you may need to delete it.
>   [image]
>
> To reformat a partition for windows, right click the partition, then
>   choose "Format", and use the NTFS file system.